# Keep only 100 new records for each user, deleting older in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `feed` json that I'd like to keep only 100 records per user. So each time I put one new record there I'd like to delete older records.

To get posts I want to keep I do:

```
feedRef = firebase.database().ref().child('feed').child(user_id).limitToLast(100);
```

How to delete the other old ones?

Answer (score 2):

Will ringbuffer solution suffice?
You allocate 100 records up front. Keep track which one is newest by storing counter that points at that record.
When new record is created update counter modulo 100 to reset it to beginning if needed, then store record where new counter points.

This way newer records will override oldest and no additional maintenance is needed.

Alternative:
Run cron job that deletes older entries. E.g. query for 100 newest entries and take oldest timestamp then delete records older then that timestamp.

This however assume maintenance tasks, and can't guarantee that only at most 100 records exists per user.
But this may be implementable without any modification to your db structure.

Comment: oh, I thought it would be easier. But I will try, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a firebase function that listens for `child_added` on each `user_id` of the `feed` object. Within the firebase function you could find and delete the oldest record of that `user_id` each time a new record is added thereby guaranteeing you 100 items each time.